# How to use Microsoft PKCS#9 SignerInfo attributes in a Java application?

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, capicom

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs(VS.85).aspx we can see that the following digital signature attributes are defined:

- Pkcs9ContentType
- Pkcs9DocumentDescription
- Pkcs9DocumentName
- Pkcs9MessageDigest
- Pkcs9SigningTime

Of those, *Pkcs9DocumentDescription* and *Pkcs9DocumentName* are not present in the [PKCS#9 specification](ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc2985.txt). I have a Java application that uses *Bouncy Castle* and I want my app to be able to create digital signatures that have these two attributes.

So, I have two questions: how to do so? Should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to manually build the attributes using the OIDs, like so:

```
ObjectIdentifier dnOid = new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1");
ObjectIdentifier ddOid = new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2");
ASN1Set nameSet = new DERSet(new ASN1Encodable[] {new DERPrintableString("name")});
ASN1Set descriptionSet = new DERSet(new ASN1Encodable[] {new DERPrintableString("description"}));
Attribute documentName = new Attribute(dnOid, nameSet);
Attribute documentDescription = new Attribute(ddOid, descriptionSet);
```

I should point out that using `DERPrintableString` for the attribute value is my best guess.  I can't find the documentation for indicating the correct type.

As for *should you*, well, there's nothing wrong with using Attributes which aren't from `PKCS #9`.  You just shouldn't rely on an external system being able to use them.

Comment: According to http://lists.iaik.tugraz.at/pipermail/jce-general/2003-November/003484.html, these attributes have type OCTET_STRING.